# When do you use vue-route and when do you use express route?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, vuejs2, vue-router

I've just developed a prototype using node.js and express.js. Here I've used Express route for CRUD'ing the backend.

server.js file:

```
app.get('/project/:id', crud.getProjectData);
```

This route will retrieve project information from the server.

Now I'm refactoring my code and i want to use Vue.js. Here they have vue-router for fetching vue components:

```
router.map({
 '/project/:id': {
    component: projectComponent,
 }
});
// I think this is the proper vue way of doing it
```

So I'm making a one page application, so how can I use routig to fetch the Vue component and the backend data? Do I only use Vue routing and then inside the component fetch the data from the backend?

Answer (score 2):

Normally, I prefer express to server API requests and Vue to server urls which are visible in the browser.

for all the API requests, you can prepend them by /api or something.

So,

Fetch API - `/api/project/:id` - this is in express.

Client Route - `/project/:id` - this is in Vue.

Also, to initiate the app, Express can return index.html and Vue can take over the front-end routing.

This kind of setup makes sure Vue and Express handle what they are meant to handle.